# Common data types: How much bytes are they?

Tags: delphi, memory

I'd like to know how much bytes a

- 32-bit integer
- ASCII character (char in C++?)
- Pointer (4 bytes?)
- Short
- Float

Takes up in Delphi, and if it is generally the same in most languages

Also, do the data types mentioned above have a constant size? I mean are the integers 0, 4, 123 and 32231 all of the same size?

Comment: All data of same type will occupy the same amount of memory, irrespective of the value.

Comment: why is this question tagged c++? it seems only delphi (pascal dialect) related...

Comment: @Gunner: no! You are incorrect! strictly speaking, that is dependant on the compiler!! if the compiler generates code that is 16bit... or 32bit or 64bit...

Comment: @tommieb75: Actually, I meant to say, for a given system, all data variables of same data type will be of same size. That is, for GNU C++ 4.0 on windows, all int will be of same size.

Answer (score 8):

A 32-bit integer is *ALWAYS* four bytes, because 1 byte = 8 bits.

- An `Integer` is a signed 32-bit integer, and a `Cardinal` is a unsigned 32-bit integer. These thus always occupy four bytes, irrespective of the value they represent. (In fact, it is an extremely important fact that simple types do have fixed widths -- low-level programming really depends on this! It is even a cornerstone part of how computers work.)
- Smaller integer types are `Smallint` (16-bit signed), `Word` (16-bit unsigned) and `Byte` (8-bit unsigned). Larger integer types are `Int64` (64-bit signed) and `UInt64` (64-bit unsigned).
- `Char` was a 1-byte `AnsiChar` prior to Delphi 2009; now it is a 2-byte `WideChar`.
- `Pointer` is always 4 bytes, because Delphi currently creates 32-bit applications only. When it supports 64-bit applications, `Pointer` will become 8 bytes.
- There are three common floating-point types in Delphi. These are `Single`, `Double` (=`Real`), and `Extended`. These occupy 4, 8, and 10 bytes, respectively.

To investigate the size of a given type, e.g. `Short`, simply try

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(SizeOf(Short)))
```

Reference:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types

Comment: Well, strictly speaking D1 is also Delphi :-)

Comment: On 64-bit, a fourth 128-bit float type will probably be added, and the 10 byte one might disappear (the x87 status in 64-bit mode is a bit dubious, but it is allowed)

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++, SizeOf(Char) = 1 byte as required by C/C++ standard.

In Delphi, SizeOf(Char) is version dependent (1 byte for non-Unicode versions, 2 bytes for Unicode versions), so Char in Delphi is more like TChar in C++.

Comment: Except that in C++, a single project can be compiled as either Ansi or Unicode with a simple compiler directive.  That is not the case in Delphi.  D2009 and later can only compile as Unicode.  Earlier versions can only compile as Ansi.

Comment: Erm, not true if we extend the question to the usage of custom string/character types, defined with an #ifdef on the compiler version. In that case, D2009+ could still compile to Ansi, while older versions (that support WideChar) could support (some sort of Unicode).  (I'm ignoring the WinAPI/VCL/RTL integration issues here of course.)

Answer (score 1):

It may be different for different machines, so you can use the following code to determine the size of integer(for examle):
`cout << "Integer size:" << sizeof(int);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to confuse you too much, but there's also an alignment issue; If you define a record like this, it will depend on the compiler how it's layout will turn out :

```
type Test = record
    A: Byte;
    B: Pointer; 
end;
```

If compiled with {$A1}, `SizeOf(Test)` will end up as 5, while compiling it with {$A4} would give you 8 (at least, on current 32 bit Delphi's that is!)
There are all sorts of little gotcha's here, so I'd advise to ignore this for now and read [an article like this](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#aligns) when the need arises ;-)

Comment: If you want the `sizeof` a record to be the sum of the `sizeof`s of every member, then simply write `packed record` instead of `record`.